# Issue with Supabase API Query - 'table_name' Not Recognized in 'select' Parameter

Tags: rest, supabase

I'm currently working on a project where I need to retrieve job information using the Supabase API. I've constructed the following query:

```
https://xitadfuakpfqasbwtomi.supabase.co/rest/v1/jobs?
job_sub_category_rel.sub_category.id=eq.4,
select=*,
city:cities!inner(id,name_ar,name_en,country:countries!inner(id)),
job_category_rel:job_category_rel!inner(id,category!inner(id,name_en,name_ar)),
job_sub_category_rel:job_sub_category_rel!inner(id,sub_category!inner(id,name_en,name_ar))
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```json
{
    "code": "PGRST108",
    "details": null,
    "hint": "Verify that 'job_sub_category_rel' is included in the 'select' query parameter.",
    "message": "'job_sub_category_rel' is not an embedded resource in this request"
}
```

The error suggests an issue with the inclusion of `job_sub_category_rel` in the `select` query parameter. I've ensured that it's included, but it seems to be not recognized as an embedded resource.

I've consulted the Supabase API documentation, but I'm unable to identify the problem. Could someone please review my query and provide insights into what might be causing this issue? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use the supabase-js library to construct the query and then see if you get the same error. If you don't get the same error then copy the url it generates from your web inspector http tab and use that in your code.